# Why can't you access Windows GUI from a background thread?

Tags: windows, multithreading, thread-safety

I know that in a Windows application background threads are not allowed to directly access GUI items. What I don't fully understand is why. The closest explanation I have found is this one:

> Access to Windows Forms controls is not inherently thread safe. If you have two or more threads manipulating the state of a control, it is possible to force the control into an inconsistent state. Other thread-related bugs are possible, such as race conditions and deadlocks. It is important to make sure that access to your controls is performed in a thread-safe way.

which is from [this MS documenation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728.aspx).

Can anybody elaborate on a specific example of what two threads could do that would put a window item into an inconsistent state?

Comment: Anything where there's shared state (like a structure) either through the API usage directly, or privately within the API could easily be messed up. The specifics of which could vary from OS version to version. If someone says their code isn't thread-safe, I never risk it with my code, and thus always practice safe-threading. :)

Answer (score 2):

Winforms and WPF are not thread-safe because Windows windows are not thread-safe.  In general, large amounts of code with lots of state are never thread-safe, it is just too hard to make the so.  It isn't limited to user32 and gdi32, a browser isn't thread-safe either for example.  Even if Microsoft went through extraordinary lengths to make windows thread-safe, it would still not work well in practice.  Because that doesn't automatically make your code thread-safe.  You'd still fight glitches if threads do not coordinate to determine what a window should look like.  A very hard to solve problem, I have the scars to prove it.  The universal solution is to make only one thread responsible for its content.

In Windows, only kernel32 is thread-safe.  Necessarily so, you wouldn't be able to safely use threads if that wasn't the case.  You see this back in the kernel32 api functions, they do very small things that affect very little state.

Comment: Actually, windows are thread-safe. (You can, for example, call `GetWindowText` from any thread.) The problem is that people who write code that use windows rarely write thread-safe code. Thread safety is hard. You update a value from one thread, but due to cache coherency issues, the value doesn't become visible to the other thread until some time later. Or you read a value from one thread, and while you're still using that value, another thread invalidates it. These sorts of bugs drive people crazy. The standard solution is to say "Don't do that. Don't even try. You will go crazy."